# Why is AJAX call ignored?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I don't know why the process ignores my AJAX call. It simply jumps from `console.log("1");` to `console.log("2");`.

Can someone explain to me what is going wrong?

```
render: function() {
  let view = this;
  component.prototype.render.call(view);

  console.log("1");

  $.ajax = ({
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    url: "news.json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(json) {

      console.log("success");

      for (let i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        let news = modelNews;
        news.title = json[i].title;
        news.type = json[i].type;
        news.img = json[i].img;
        news.link = json[i].link;

        view.$('#newsfeed').append(news.getNewsFeedLook());
      }
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log("error");
    }
  });

  console.log("2");

}
```

Comment: You need to call the `$.ajax` function, here you are assigning to it: `$.ajax = ({ ...`

Comment: You are *overriding* `$.ajax`. Not calling it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not calling the ajax function of jQuery, it is reassigning it.

```
$.ajax = ({
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    url: "news.json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(json) {

      console.log("success");

      for (let i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        let news = modelNews;
        news.title = json[i].title;
        news.type = json[i].type;
        news.img = json[i].img;
        news.link = json[i].link;

        view.$('#newsfeed').append(news.getNewsFeedLook());
      }
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log("error");
    }
  });
```

This is the proper call, a function call that is.
Pay closer attention to minor error like this!

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    url: "news.json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(json) {

      console.log("success");

      for (let i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        let news = modelNews;
        news.title = json[i].title;
        news.type = json[i].type;
        news.img = json[i].img;
        news.link = json[i].link;

        view.$('#newsfeed').append(news.getNewsFeedLook());
      }
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log("error");
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thank you. That helped. I just trusted too much IntelliJ code representation.